# ValueError when making histogram of excel data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make histogram of an excel data. I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
data=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',header=1, parse_cols="Q")
plt.hist(data, bin=10)
plt.show()
```

But it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-0ffa7ab287c3>", line 4, in <module>
    plt.hist(data, bin=10)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2890, in hist
    stacked=stacked, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5562, in hist
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1678, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1685, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1052, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2565, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1181, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))

  File "index.pyx", line 129, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3656)

  File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3534)

  File "hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:11911)

  File "hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:11864)

KeyError: 0
```

This is how my data looks like

[image: file]

Does anybody have an idea about how can I fix this?

Comment: Please give the full stacktrace

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Can you please include the `print` output of `data`. And btw the parameter for `hist()` is called `bins` not `bin`